# Help with finding limit of function with 2 variables

Tags: limits

Find $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{e^{\sin(x^2+y^2)}-1}{x^2+y^2}$$

I have tried taking limits when $y=x$ and when $y=-x$ but failing to get close to an answer.

Comment: Can you see that it's going to be the same as $\lim_{p\to0}\frac{e^{\sin p}-1}{p}$?

Comment: Welcome to the site ! By the way, where are you located ? Your profile does not say much. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Method 1.** One may write, as $x^2+y^2 \to 0$, by the use of Taylor series expansions, $$ \begin{align}
     \sin(x^2+y^2)&=x^2+y^2+O((x^2+y^2)^3)
     \\\\e^{\sin(x^2+y^2)}&=1+x^2+y^2+O((x^2+y^2)^2) \end{align} $$
  giving, as $x^2+y^2 \to 0$, $$
     \frac{e^{\sin(x^2+y^2)}-1}{x^2+y^2}=1+O(x^2+y^2). $$
- **Method 2.** One may write, as $x^2+y^2 \to 0$,    $$ \frac{e^{\sin(x^2+y^2)}-1}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\color{red}{e^{\sin(x^2+y^2)}-1}}{\color{red}{\sin(x^2+y^2)}}\times
     \frac{\color{blue}{\sin(x^2+y^2)}}{\color{blue}{x^2+y^2}}. $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, managed to get an answer using your 2nd method. :)

Comment: You are welcome.